# How to use class level state in a style function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a following react class component.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  heading: {
    margin: 10,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    overflow: expanded ? 'scroll' : 'hidden' // I am trying to use the state here , but gives error
  }
})

@((withStyles as any)(styles))
export class Viwer extends React.Component<Iviwer> { 

 state = {
    expanded: ''
  }
  handleChange = panel => {
    const { expanded } = this.state
    if (expanded === panel) {
      this.setState({
        expanded: null
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        expanded: panel
      })
    }
  }
  
 render() {
    const {
      handleChange,
      defaultDeleteAction,
      props: {
        classes,
        panelName,
        styles
      },
      state: { expanded }
    } = this 
   
   return (
     <div
              onClick={() => {
                handleChange(panelName)
              }}>
              <Typography variant='body1' className={classes.heading}>
                {panelName}
              </Typography>
            </div>
  
  )
}
```

So, In the above code, I am trying to use the `expanded` state in a styles , but it gives compile time error. On click event gets trigger as soon as user clicks on the div ,so here I want to apply the css conditionally.

How do I fix this error. Any help would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey ganeshk, it will throw error because you are using the `expanded` variable outside of the scope it is defined in

Comment: Okay, with the current implementation, is there any way to do this